# I get this error when using namespace in laravel 5.7.14

Tags: ajax, laravel

```
<? php           

namespace App;           

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;           

class Post extends Model { 

    protected $table = 'posts';

}
```

Arguments

> "syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_NAMESPACE)"

Comment: Does your file start with `<?php`?

Comment: I think the problem is the space between `<?` and `php`

Comment: it should written `<?php` not `<? php`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
   //...
});
```

I think issue in your laravel version but you will try this i hope it will work for you.